# Calling a subfunction from another function

Tags: android

Here I want to call `sortByDateModified()` function and include the line `Arrays.sort(files, filecomparatorByLastModified)` inside that function. But the line `Arrays.sort(files, filecomparatorByLastModified)`  is located into another function in `public void getDir(String dirPath)`. How can I call a subfunction of another function from a function...

```
public void onClick(View v) { sortByDateModified(); }       

public void getDir(String dirPath) {
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root)) {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());    
    }

    Arrays.sort(files, filecomparatorByLastModified);
    Arrays.sort(files, filecomparator);

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File file = files[i];

        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }
            else { item.add(file.getName()); }
        }   
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);   
}
```

Comment: "Subfunction"? There's no such thing. You call it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, you would have to share either the directory or file array variable.

```
File[] fileList = null;

public void methodLikeOnCreateOrConstructor( String dirPath )
{
   //needs to be initialized before onClick could be called
   fileList = getDir( dirPath );

}

public void onClick(View v) {
   Arrays.sort(fileList, filecomparatorByLastModified);      
}

public void getDir( String dirPath ) 
{
   //...
   File f = new File( dirPath );
   files = f.listFiles();

   //...
}
```

Comment: Its not doing that as beacuse the files parameter in this function is initialized in getDir() function. I tried to initialize those variables in the onClick() method but still no difference.